# Rails 4 redirect loop error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

Using devise, cancan, and rolify to setup an auth stack on my rails 4.0.2 application and im getting a redirect_loop error when trying to view the `users/sign_in` or `users/sign_up`.

does anyone know what causes this?

my routes file

```
Rails::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :events
  resources :users

  root :to => "home#index"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

end
```

Comment: can you also share your registrations controller?

Answer (score 0):

remove line: `resources :users` and then try......

```
Rails::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :events
  #resources :users # comment or remove this line

  root :to => "home#index"

  devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "registrations"}

end
```